# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '_process' (JavaScript/ Browserify)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, browserify

I am using browserify to create a bundle of my javascript file, which resulted in an error saying it could not find fs. To combat this I was told to use --no-builtins

Now I am getting an error message 'Cannot find module '_process'. As the code was auto generated, I do not know how to fix this

My javascript file reads in a document which has been uploaded, then queries a mysql database

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get errors about `_process` with --no-builtins, that means that your app uses some of the Node builtins, so it *must* be bundled without that flag.

> My javascript file reads in a document which has been uploaded, then queries a mysql database

Unfortunately, that is not something that is possible in the browser. Querying a MySQL database can only be done on the server, and reading a file using `fs` must also only be done in Node.js. In browserify, you can load documents over HTTP using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), but the document has to be publically accessible or be made available through an API.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will have to attempt to do it another way